# Can I use silicone latex to plug hole in a tree?

Tags: repair, landscaping

I put some small 1/2" holes around the trunk on a river birch tree and gave it an iron treatment. The instructions called to seal the holes with latex caulk, but I only have latex caulk with silicone added in. Is it a problem to use it with silicone to seal small holes in the tree?

Answer (score 5):

There is no need to seal the holes at all.  The natural healing process that woody plants use is to grow around the wound and eventually cover it over.

[Standards](http://tcia.org/files/Tree%20Pruning%20to%20ANSI%20Standards.pdf) for [good pruning practice](http://extension.psu.edu/natural-resources/forests/urban-community/publications/pruning-landscape-trees)s around the [world](http://treelogic.com.au/facts/tree-wound-dressings/) are to not use wound paint of any sort.  It can act to hold moisture in and promote fungus and decay agents.

Take a break and let nature do the job for you...

Answer (score 2):

It's not a problem. The tree will protect itself from the wounds, which by your description seem fairly minor (unless it is a small, immature tree). Room temperature vulcanizing silicone releases a small amount of acetic acid while curing. While it is toxic and slightly corrosive, the small amount released by a siliconized latex caulk compared to a non-silicone latex caulk would be insignificant.

By the way, IMO you should use a pruning sealer instead.